# Upload UWP App to Microsoft Store has validation error

Tags: xamarin, uwp

I tried to upload my .appxupload file to Submission in Microsoft Store, but I got this message:

> Package acceptance validation error: The package file format for
> LoginNavigation.UWP_1.0.143.0_x86_x64_arm.appxbundle is invalid:
> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
> {378E0446-5384-43B7-8877-E7DBDD883446} failed due to the following
> error: 800b0101 A required certificate is not within its validity
> period when verifying against the current system clock or the
> timestamp in the signed file. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800B0101)..
> Update the package and try again.

I built Xamarin App with:
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.7.0

Does anybody has the same Problem ?

Thanks

Comment: I actually have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I am having the same problem. I think there's an issue with the Partner Centre. Biggest suggestion is to create support ticket. Go here https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/support/ > click contact us > select develop topic "dashboard" > issue type "app submissions" > submit an incident.

Comment: Try again now. Seems to be working https://twitter.com/archiecoder/status/1293271832330633217?s=20

Comment: Thanks for letting us know.

Comment: It works now, thanks